# Adding an extension in Visual studio removes an existing extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, plugins, visual-studio-extensions

I have installed our Visual studio extension (source control extension, similar to TFS/Git). It was shown in the toolbar and the command options were available on right click of files/folder in Solution explorer tab. After installing other extension (**Visual Lint**), our plugin is no more available in Visual studio. It is not even listed in source control selection option as well. But it is shown in **Control panel**. Upon **Repair** of the plugin from Control panel, it is visible in Visual studio. Currently we are in the process of finding the root cause of this issue. Any ideas or suggestions, what could be the root cause of this?

Comment: According to your description, it seems that the extension named "Visual Lint" cause the issue, I would suggest that you could contract the extension author to check where the issue is.

Comment: Both the extensions might have same GUID. Check the VSIX's GUIDs in the manifest files.